# Can materialized views be used as a fast denomalized big table?

Tags: oracle, bigtable, denormalization, materialized-views

Can Oracle Materialized views be used to join multiple related tables having foreign keys to create a larger denormalized big table which is refreshed instantaneously?

On some [investigations](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm#48516), it says that joins are not allowed while using fast refresh.

Is it my assumption which is wrong that i can do this sort of thing with Oracle Materalized views?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the tables are local (i.e. you are not trying to replicate the data from a remote database and do the joins all in one step), the restrictions you need to be aware of are listed in the [Data Warehousing Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#sthref537), not the replication manual.  The specific set of restrictions depends on the Oracle version but you should be able to create a fast-refreshable denormalized view of your data.